# No database selected although I have

Tags: php, html, mysql

Get this from error-message **invalid query: No database selected**, even though I have selected database in my **template.php**

This is the code im making right now. It's a table that displays users for the admin: **anvandare.php**:

```
      $query = "select * from user";

      $run = mysql_query($query);
if (!$run){
  die('invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){

      $email = $row['email'];
      $company = $row['company'];
      $fname = $row['fname'];
      $licensID = $row['licensID'];
      $tel = $row['tel'];

?>
        <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $company; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $licensID; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tel; ?></td>
        <td> ta bort </td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
            </div> <!-- Stänger jumbotron --> 
          </div> <!-- Stänger jumbotronbekraftat --> 
        </div> <!-- Stänger container --> 
<?php        
  echo $navigation_admin;
  echo $header;
  ?>
```

This is the databas.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
   session_regenerate_id();
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Webbprojekt");
   mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf-8");
?>
```

How do I sort this problem out? Because in the `include (template.php)` I have connected with my database.

Comment: Show your connection code too!!

Comment: Call your `template.php` in your `anvandare.php`

Comment: add `mysql_connect`, and instead of using `mysql_*` please use `mysqli_* OR PDO` as `mysql_*` is deprecated in PHP 7

Comment: @Ms.Nehal It was deprecated in PHP 5.5. It is completely absent in PHP7.

Comment: Please see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: @Oldskool, sorry I wrote it wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

use the above code to make database connection 
For more Info

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; $db="dbname"; $charset="utf8"; $user="root"; $pass="";
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
?>
```

use this in your template for more secure, but u can use this for your project:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new code with PDO should be like as below

```
$db_con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db-name', 'username', 'password');
    $statement = $db_con->prepare("select * from user");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   foreach($result as $row)
   {
     $email = $row['email'];
     $company = $row['company'];
    $fname = $row['fname'];
     $licensID = $row['licensID'];
     $tel = $row['tel'];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your database.php you have created connection using mysqli_*() but in your .php you have used mysql_query($query); Instead of using mysql_* use mysqli_*

I mean to say use either mysql_*() or mysqli_*() throughout the project.As mysql_*() are depreciated so use mysqli_*()